# Using Except keyword in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the except keyword in c# for the first time and I have been struggling a lot with this. If possible could you please have a look into my function and let me know where I am wrong.

I need to return the string of arrays. indivEmails1 and indivEmails2 contains an array of email id's. I need to return an email id's which are not in indivEmails2 but not in indivEmails1. But it has to be string of array.

```
public string[] getNewCCEmailsIDs(WorkOrderModel model)
{
    string[] emailids = null;
    var result = _db.WorkOrders
        .Where(w => w.idWorkOrder == model.idWorkOrder && w.idCompany == model.idCompany)
        .Select(w => new {w.Status, w.ExternalEmails});
     if (dbItem.Status == (int) WorkOrderStatus.Approved )
    {
        string NewCCEmail = "";
        var comEmails1 = dbItem.ExternalEmails.Trim(';');
        string[] indivEmails1 = comEmails1.Split(';');

        string comEmails2 = model.ExternalEmails.Trim(';');
        string[] indivEmails2 = comEmails2.Split(';');


        IEnumerable<string> emailsToAdd = indivEmails2.Except(indivEmails1);

        //NewCCEmail = emailsToAdd;
        }

        if (NewCCEmail != "") // when client delete an email id from CC and press save.
            emailids = NewCCEmail.Split(';');
    }
    return emailids;
}
```

I am getting below error. I have looked eveywhere but no luck.

```
Error   54  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Users\Bakul\Documents\GitHub\Maxpanda\Maxpanda\Controllers\WorkOrderController.cs    930 25  Maxpanda
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: .ToArray() maybe?

Comment: just add `indivEmails2.Except(indivEmails1).ToList();` and you will see it will work fine..

Comment: `Except` is not a "keyword", it's just a regular extension method -  [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()`

```
 List<string> emailsToAdd = indivEmails2.Except(indivEmails1).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think so he need to add `ToArray();`  while returning `emailids` as its already declared as array only, `ToList()` is prefect ..

Comment: @BharatPatidar yes i dint notice that :) modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one. Changed code to below and it worked.

string[] emailsToAdd = indivEmails2.Except(indivEmails1).ToArray();